# list directories which has only txt files using regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I have this regex

```
"\\\"([^\"]*)\\\""
```

which returns all directories.
But i only want directories which have xyz.xml file

Please anyone help me out.

```
 string url = //some url
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);

                using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        string html = reader.ReadToEnd();

                        Regex regex = new Regex("\\\"([^\"]*)\\\"");
                        //  Regex regex = new Regex("\\\"(xml)");
                        MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(html);
                        if (matches.Count > 0)
                        {
                            foreach (Match match in matches)
                            {
                                if (match.Success)
                                {
                                 //further code
```

Comment: for clarification: You want only all directories which contain xml files?

Comment: Do you have to use `regex`? *Linq* solution seems to be easier.

Comment: can you post the code in which you use this regex? I think regex is not really necessary here

Comment: I want to list all directories from an http url, which have xyz.xml files in them

Comment: Please ask for clarification before down voting the question. I'm at an early phase of learning.

Comment: usually you never reach those people who downvote you with your comments. At least that is my experience

Comment: please provide the code where you use the regex.

Comment: I have updated my question with the code @MongZhu

Comment: I didn't downvote anyone here. That's possibly done because this is about regular expression beginners topic, I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put `new Regex("\"([^\"]+\\.xml)\"")` that should return all files ending with .xml.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. It worked well for me. But there is one more problem. I'm trying to iterate recursively through all the directories but my code does not do so. So it cannot find xyz.xml files within sub directories. Please help me out. Thanks

Comment: That's topic of a different question. Please close this and open a new one.